# Python bloomberg API xbbg: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'values'

Tags: python, bloomberg

i'm getting the following error message
File "C:\Users\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\xbbg\core\process.py", line 137, in process_ref
    for sec in data.values():

AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'values'

when running:

```
from xbbg import blp
blp.bdp(tickers='NVDA US Equity', flds=['Security_Name','GICS_Sector_Name'])
```

any one else having this problem? 
Thank you

Comment: what version are you using? and if you load one field at a time, what do you see?

Answer (score 0):

To check if you have the API environment correctly installed and it works, try the BLPDemoTool.exe tool:
[Error message DemoTool](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DXc7k.jpg)

If you get an error here, contact BBG help and try againg. In my case this solved the issue

Answer (score 0):

So it looks like this error tends to come when you've hit your data limit with bloomberg. I've run into this error a couple times before and it always mysteriously disappeared the day after and I was not exactly sure why it happened until I dug deeper.

This can be fixed if you ask the bloomberg help desk for a data extension. They place a daily and monthly limit on the number of times you use their API. If you exceed the limit, then this error starts to show up.